# Reset stack after navigate to login screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am making a react-native mobile app, and I have a navigation drawer with a logout button on it. I know how to navigate from there to the login screen, using `props.navigation.navigate('Login')`, but the problem is that if the user does this, they can still open the drawer from the Login screen and navigate back to one of the other screens, or press the back button on Android.

I guess I could do a check on the Login screen if the user came from another page and then disable the open drawer button, but that seems kinda hacky. I was wondering if there is a correct way of doing this, perhaps to reset the stack upon arrival on the Login, I'm not sure.

Comment: take a look at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html . you can reset stack and dispatch to your login page.

Comment: You shouldn't include Login Screen in createDrawerNavigator, you should include in createStackNavigator, so you won't get Drawer.

Comment: Well done @Kranthi, your comment was my solution. I had the Login screen in createDrawerNavigator, when it was supposed to be in the createStackNavigator of App. Now I can just reset the stack, and then navigate to the Login screen in the createStackNavigator, and it works.

Comment: @Amas yes my problem is solved, but I didn't use your solution. Thank you for your answer all the same.

Answer (score 6):

Your implementation is not good. from the details you gave i think all of your pages are just in one `stack`. i recommend you to separate Authentication and App stacks. for this i highly recommend this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

but resetting stack :

> **reset**
>
> The reset action wipes the whole navigation state and replaces it with
>   the result of several actions.
>
> - index - number - required - Index of the active route on routes array in navigation state.
> - actions - array - required - Array of Navigation Actions that will replace the navigation state.
> - key - string or null - optional - If set, the navigator with the given key will reset. If null, the root navigator will reset.

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

source : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html

Comment: Yeah I got it. I couldnt use this reset method because the Login screen was in the createDrawerNavigator function. So the solution for me was to move the Login screen from the createDrawerNavigator to the createStackNavigator. Then I could use the reset method and navigate to the Login screen from the drawer menu.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset your navigation stack when you logout

first define the logout action

```
const logoutAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })],
});
```

then on logout do

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(logoutAction);
```