# How to reset React Navigation to initial default state (the state that the app opens)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I'm trying to reset the navigation state to default state (whatever is when the app is first opened without any actions) upon user logout.

How do I achieve that?

I've seen [Reset stack after navigate to login screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098696/reset-stack-after-navigate-to-login-screen) yet it still specifies a route and I don't know what to put there. I've tried providing `undefined` yet got an error.

How can I make React Navigation to just purge everything and act as if the app opened? I'm looking for something like `StackActions.reset({})` (pseudocode, doesn't work) that is empty, and trigger whatever React Navigation does on app start.

Comment: This answer might be close to what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/62980152/11239071

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional routes, as suggested in the documents for [authentication flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#how-it-will-work)

like below

```js
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
);
```

And the `isSignedIn` can be handled by `Context Api` or `redux`

Comment: It's a nice idea especially if I was first designing the app, yet this isn't what I'm asking. We already have the logic in a working app, I can't change that. I just need to reset the state, regardless of how I structured the app and rendering.